# How to make Rails Heroku Application Contents Searchable in google?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Heroku Rails App with some blogs but I doesn't seem to be searchable with google. Eg. I have an article on the site and when I type the article's tile in google I even included Heroku and the name of my app in the search but I did not retrieve link to my app's article.

Answer (score 2):

Check Google's Webmasters tool: https://www.google.com/webmasters/
The html file that Google gives you to verify your site must be placed in /myappname/public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add meta tags to your pages, check this [article](http://www.iacquire.com/blog/18-meta-tags-every-webpage-should-have-in-2013) out. (Focus on `keywords`, `title`, `description`).

And you need to ping search engines (like google, bing) with your site map. You may use [sitemap_generator gem](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator).